# Create a Searchlight Animation with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an animated searchlight with css or javascript, whichever performs better. I threw together something with CSS: http://codepen.io/jhlavac/pen/bNprea

Hopefully that will give you an idea of where I'm going with this.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="light_beam"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
background:black;
}
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height:460px;
}
#light_beam {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:500px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 400px solid yellow;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
#light_beam {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s; 
  -o-transition: all 2s; 
  -ms-transition: all 2s; 
}

#light_beam { 
  -ms-transform: skew(50deg,0deg); 
  -webkit-transform: skew(50deg,0deg); 
  transform: skew(50deg,0deg); 
}
#light_beam:hover { 
  left: 850px;
  -ms-transform: skew(-50deg,0deg); 
  -webkit-transform: skew(-50deg,0deg); 
  transform: skew(-50deg,0deg); 
}
```

The problem is that the bottom of the light beam moves during the animation. I need it to remain stationary, while the beam moves across the page. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform-origin: 100% 100%` on `#light-beam:hover` to make it fixed.

### [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/XJdaNw)

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 460px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#light_beam {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 500px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 400px solid yellow;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
#light_beam {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  transition: all 2s;
}
#light_beam {
  -webkit-transform: skew(50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(50deg, 0deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
#light_beam:hover {
  left: 850px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-50deg, 0deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="light_beam"></div>
</div>
```